# Fundamental theorem of Calculus for nonincreasing function defined on an open interval

Tags: calculus, integration, lebesgue-integral

I have a question about the integrability of function on an open interval.

Let $f:(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a positive, nonincreasing and integrable (Riemann or Lebesgue) on (0,1). Define

$$F(x):=\int_0^x f(t)dt,\text{ for all }x\in [0,1].$$

Is it possible to prove that $F$ is continuous on $[0,1]?$ It seems that the statement holds if $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ but I do not know the proof in general?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the dominated convergence theorem
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} F(x) =\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \int_0^1 1_{[0;x)}(t) f(t) dt = \int_0^1 1_{[0;x_0)}(t) f(t) dt = F(x_0).$$
All we need is that $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it!

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Theorem 3 in the following lecture notes also shows that $F$ is absolutely continuous. Note that we also need to extend the function $f$ into a new function defined on $[0,1]$ but the new function is still integral since the Lebesgue integral is unchanged if we add or remove a finite number of points in the interval.

https://math-wiki.com/images/2/2f/88341leb_fund_thm.pdf

Comment: I don't quite understand. Why do we need to extend our function to $[0;1]$?

Comment: Because the fundamental theorem of calculus only states for a closed interval, not open interval like $(0,1)$.